# Need experts guidance - ADM 201

Tags: certification

I am a customer relationship manager in a real estate company had an experience of 7 years in the same filed, Need your guidance is it good for me to become certified ADM 201 and can i get a good job after this. I have no experience of this field as i am from commerce stream and done MBA in finance.

Comment: Sonali the stackexchage site and way of working works best on specific and detailed questions which can either be answered correctly or not. Therefor questions which are too broad, are discussion prone or will lead to subjective answers are discouraged and considered off topic.

Comment: Hi Sonali - this is a good question, but, as @SamuelDeRycke says, it doesn't really fit into the StackExchange format. A GREAT place to ask this would be https://success.salesforce.com/answers